# Regex: Remove a second pair of paranthesis in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy

I would like to remove the second set of parenthesis in a string. Preferably with this Java method: replaceAll()

thus far I have tried:

1. `return device.replaceAll("(\w+\s*\w*)","");`
   which throws an error: `unexpected char \`
2. `return device.replaceAll("[()]","").trim();`
   which removes all the parenthesis and trailing spaces

Here is my method:

```
private static String parseDeviceDescription(String device) {
    device = device.replaceAll("apply discount","");
    return device.replaceAll("(\w+\s*\w*)","");
}
```

Here is how I call the method:

```
String device = parseDeviceDescription("device name (2018) (apply discount)");
System.out.println("The device description is: " + device);
```

Expected Results:

```
"device name (2018)"
```

Comment: `return device.replaceAll("\\(\\w+\\s*\\w*\\)$", "");`

Comment: Hi YCF_L: I tried that and the output is: "() ()" (So I think i wrote the regex wrong) any suggestions? Thanks! =)

Comment: check demo https://www.ideone.com/YqbsEG

Comment: You rules are incomplete: 1) What if input only has one set of parenthesis, e.g. `a b (c)`? --- 2) What if input has 3 or more sets, e.g. `a b (c) (d) (e)`? --- 3) What if there is text between sets of parenthesis, e.g. `a (b) c (d) (e) f (g) (h)`? --- Your simple "remove the second set" would mean to remove *nothing* (#1), `(d)` (#2), and `(d)` (#3).

Comment: YCF_L:  My compiler is throwing this error: "illegal string body char after $" -- for this code: return device.replaceAll("\\(\\w+\\s*\\w*\\)$", "");

Comment: Andreas: Very true the dynamic changing nature of a string is unpredictable in most cases, but this one is always static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all after first `)` (inclusive) with `)`

```
"device name (2018) (apply discount)".replaceAll("\\).*",")")
```

Answer (score 1):

If we interpret "remove the second set of parenthesis" as meaning that if two sets of parenthesis-enclosed strings are consecutive, remove the second set, we can write it like this:

```
private static String parseDeviceDescription(String device) {
    return device.replaceAll("(\\([^()]*\\))\\s*\\([^()]*\\)", "$1");
}
```

*Test*

```
String[] devices = {
        "device name (2018) (apply discount)",
        "a b (c)",
        "a b (c) (d) (e)",
        "a (b) c (d) (e) f (g) (h)",
        "a (b) (c) (d) (e) (f) (g) (h)"
};
for (String device : devices)
    System.out.println(parseDeviceDescription(device));
```

*Output*

```
device name (2018)
a b (c)
a b (c) (e)
a (b) c (d) f (g)
a (b) (d) (f) (h)
```

See also demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jW4X73/1).

*Explained*

```
(              Start capture group #1
  \([^()]*\)     Match `(text)` where `text` cannot contain parenthesis
)              End capture group #1
\s*            Match white-spaces, if any
\([^()]*\)     Match `(text)` where `text` cannot contain parenthesis

$1             Insert test from capture group #1
```

In English, it matches a two sets of parenthesis-enclosed text, optionally separated by spaces, and retains the first set.

Comment: Andreas: Thank you very much for explaining that all in detail, that really helps me out alot =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.substring()` method.

First get the index of your first closing parenthesis '`)`' with `device.indexOf(")")`

Then pass this to the `substring()` method, something like this:

```
    return device.substring(0,device.indexOf(")"));
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but I brought this up to my boss before, and they want as little lines of code as possible. So I am at the mercy of regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that we wish to remove  `(apply discount)`, which we can likely use this simple greedy expression:

```
(.*)(\s+\(.*)
```

and replace it with capturing group #1

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z91Haz/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(.*)(\\s+\\(.*)";
final String string = "device name (2018) (apply discount)";
final String subst = "\\1";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Comment: Hey Emma, I'm working on testing to see if that regex will work in my replaceAll() method (your guess is correct too=) )

Comment: That is so strange when I pass "(.*)(\\s+\\(.*)" in as an argument, it says the argument types are not applicable. Maybe it thinks there is another parameter